# Is Fantastic Beasts 4 still going ahead?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, fantastic-beasts

I've heard recently that Fantastic Beasts 4 is no longer going to be made, and since they have already put so much time and money into the previous films in the series, I don't understand why. I can't find anything official saying whether it is or isn't going ahead so I'm just wondering if someone else can find anything?

Comment: lol. No it's not. - https://indianexpress.com/article/entertainment/hollywood/secrets-of-dumbledore-box-office-disaster-fantastic-beasts-franchise-future-jk-rowling-7886371/

Comment: If it was official either way you **would** find something... so clearly it's still in limbo.

Comment: “since they have already put so much time and money into the previous films in the series, I don't understand why” — please allow me to briefly [blow your mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunk_cost)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Imagine having to tell your boss that instead of making three billion dollars, you've only made $1.6Bn.

Comment: @Valorum I’d just immediately resign out of pure shame.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The official word is that the series is "parked"

> *"With Beasts, it's all just parked. We made those three movies, the
> last one through a pandemic, and it was enormous fun but it was tough.
> We were actually filming when there wasn't a vaccine. Thankfully, no
> one got sick, but we did have the most detailed protocols in place."*
>
> *"We're all so proud of [Fantastic Beasts: The Secrets of Dumbledore]
> and when it went out into the world, we just needed to sort of stop
> and pause, and take it easy," Yates continued, presumably referencing
> the sequel's negative reviews and disappointing box office takings.*
>
> <sub><sup>[JK Rowling’s Fantastic Beasts film franchise abruptly ‘parked’](https://metro.co.uk/2023/10/27/jk-rowlings-fantastic-beasts-film-franchise-shelved-its-parked-19729137/)</sup></sub>

and

> *"With Beasts for a minute, it’s all just parked. We got to the end of
> [the third film, 2020’s Fantastic Beasts: The Secrets of Dumbledore]
> and we’re all so proud of that movie, and when it went out into the
> world, we just needed to sort of stop and pause, and take it easy."*
>
> <sub><sup>[Harry Potter director David Yates says Fantastic Beasts series is "parked" right now](https://www.gamesradar.com/harry-potter-director-david-yates-fantastic-beasts-parked/)</sup></sub>

In reality, having [lost the studio hundreds of millions of dollars](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/films/2022/04/19/secrets-dumbledores-box-office-hasnt-killed-fantastic-beasts/#:%7E:text=The%20global%20total%20is%20%24193,still%20be%20a%20profitable%20outcome.) and damaged the franchise, it's **parked in the graveyard**.

Comment: I feel like a combination of Rowling's anti-transgender comments,  Johnny Depp's domestic violence controversy, and the general feeling that the story was being stretched out without a coherent direction ultimately doomed it.

Comment: @Adamant - For me it was the fact that JKR insisted on playing screenwriter. This is, despite her manifold talents, clearly not one of them.

Comment: @Adamant what about Ezra Miller's *everything*? He was in all three movies(unlike Johnny Depp) and the plot pretty much revolved around his character.

Comment: Just a comment that those two quotes are both taken from the same podcast interview, seemingly quoting the same piece of the conversation, the two journalists have just transcribed and edited it slightly differently. More useful than quoting both would be to explain who is being quoted: David Yates, who directed the three Fantastic Beasts films so far. That means he's very likely to _know_ the situation, but isn't the one actually _deciding_ it - regardless of the use of "we", he will almost certainly be waiting for Warner Bros to decide, they will not be waiting for him.

Comment: @Adamant Any room for the chance these just weren't good movies? I've seen one or two or three, and the only thing I remember from them is that beasts are magical. Michael Bay's movies have more soul.

Comment: @Therac I think, Adamant’s comment did give room for the chance these just weren't good movies by saying “*and the general feeling that the story was being stretched out without a coherent direction*” though I would say it isn’t just a feeling and maybe this should have come first.